# Angularjs slow with a table

Tags: angularjs, performance

I'm having a table with about 30 rows and about 10 columns. The rows are a subrange of a much bigger set (which I do manually in order to avoid huge DOM). The columns are stored in a list like `[{name: "firstname", width: 200}, {name: "married", type: "bool"}]`, which allows some flexibility (like showing the property "married" as a checkbox).

So there are just about 300 fields, yet the digest cycle takes about one second (on my i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz).

I'm having troubles interpreting the Batarang performance page. It says

```
p.name | translate  16.0%  139.6ms
e[c.name]           15.8%  138.4ms
c.name | translate  11.1%   96.3ms
```

The meaning of the (sparsely named) variables is clear to me:

- `e` stands for entity, i.e., table row.
- `p` stands for property and only occurs outside of the table.
- `c` stands for column.
- `e[c.name]` stands for the field content (from entity `e` the property named by `c`).

But the performance figures make little sense:

- `p.name` gets only used maybe 10 times, *how can it take that long?*
- `c.name | translate` occurs only 10 times, too (in the header row), *how can it take that long?*

I'm aware of `{::a_once_only_bound_expression}`, and I tried it, but without much success. What I'd actually need is the following:

- When `c` changes, re-create the whole table (this happens only exceptionally, so I don't care about speed).
- When `e` changes, re-create its whole row (when there's a change, then only in a single row).

*Any way to achieve this?*

### A solution idea

I guess, what I need could be achieved using a directive stripping off all angular stuff from the row after rendering:

- drop all child scopes
- with all their watches
- but keep all the HTML and listeners

I could add a single watch per row responsible for the repaint if needed.

*Does it make sense?*

### Update

I've been rather busy working on the application - improving other things than performance. I was very lucky and got some performance as a bonus. Then I simplified the pages a little bit and the speed is acceptable now. At least for now.

Still:

- I don't trust the above Batarang performance values.
- *I'm still curious how to implement the above solution idea and if it makes sense.*

Comment: Without any code it's impossible to reason about the problem. _"c.name | translate occurs only 10 times"_ That's not the point. The question is how often does it get evaluated? _"p.name gets only used maybe 10 times, how can it take that long?"_ The stats say `p.name | translate`, which makes a huge difference. If you don't change the defaults the `translate` filter is stateful and therefore expensive.

Comment: @zeroflagL How often gets `c.name | translate` evaluated? I guess each occurrence once per digest cycle and it's the digest cycle what takes too long. Or am I wrong with it? If so, how can I find out? +++ Good point about the slow stateful cycle, I'll look into it. But >10 ms per translation???

Comment: An expression can(!) be tested / evaluated multiple times per digest cycle. And a stateful filter is equal to "has changed".

Comment: check this doc it will help you. https://coderwall.com/p/d_aisq/speeding-up-angularjs-s-digest-loop

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna look [NgTable](http://ng-table.com/#/) which places inputs from json data as rows and columns maybe solves your performance issue either, I recommend checkout for that